# How to convert VARCHAR to NVARCHAR mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8

Say I have:

```
    ID                      Title
 ------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |                   ماهر زين                   |
 ------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently it's data type is set to `VARCHAR(255)` with collation=`utf8-default collation`.

Based On research I had I found that You have to have Table column with the data type set to `NVARCHAR` to be able to store unicode or arabic characters. So I tried to change the Data Type of my column to `NVARCHAR` But it gives this error:

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `db`.`table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `NAME` `NAME` NVARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

Error:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
>   Executing:
>   ALTER TABLE `db`.`table` 
>   CHANGE COLUMN `NAME` `NAME` NVARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
>
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 2
>   SQL Statement:
>   ALTER TABLE `db`.`table` 
>   CHANGE COLUMN `NAME` `NAME` NVARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL

FYI: I'm doing this conversion with MySql workbench manually.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I can see the `NVARCHAR` while going to `workbench -> table -> settings -> column -> Data Type ->` I have `NVARCHAR` available but it is not changable so far

Comment: I guess you are not allowed to provide a `CHARACTER SET` in this case because `utf8` is predefined but please read the link I posted below - `NVARCHAR` will NOT change anything

Comment: @Okay the link clearly states that `CHAR & NCHAR` is predefined as `utf8` But the Problem as I said bellow is:  i'm requesting the data from eclipse java, which then it show the arabic characters as ?????? ???

Comment: Guess you don't have to write `NAME` _twice_ in the command. Nonetheless, your problem seems to be on the client-side (eg lack of `SET NAMES 'UTF-8'`), so this ALTER TABLE wouldn't solve it.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy The query is being generated by MySql workbench. And by the problem do you mean at my eclipse Java code?

Comment: Without database, is your Java-program able to produce Arabian output?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for `NVARCHAR` here as Mysql handles Unicode fine with `VARCHAR`. (Actually, `NVARCHAR` is just `VARCHAR` with predefined `utf8` char set - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-national.html)

Maybe you are confusing it with MSSQL?

Comment: See Actuall thing is that i'm requesting the data from eclipse java, which then it show the arabic characters as ?????? ???

Comment: Funny, I didn't knew these aliases existed.

Comment: Do the number of characters match? I had this happen to me when the font (in MySQL workbench) couldn't display the characters

Comment: @ReneS The Actual row is as `ماهر زين ومصطفى جيجيلي - بِكَ مُلهِمي - Maher Zain | Mustafa Ceceli - Bika Moulh` and the output I get is: `???? ??? ?????? ?????? - ???? ??????? - Maher Zain | Mustafa Ceceli - Bika Moulh`

Answer (score 2):

I see 3 Questions from you that all seem to boil down to Arabic turning into "question marks".  Search for that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .  It discusses the likely causes.

However, you have tried some ALTERs -- These may have made things *worse*.  So let's do some diagnosing.  Do `SELECT HEX(...)` as discussed in that link under "Test the data".  The hex for 'ماهر', if correctly stored as utf8, should show as `D985 D8A7 D987 D8B1`.  If you see anything different, the problem gets messier.

`3F3F3F3F` (hex for 4 question marks) is what you get if latin1 is involved.  `C399E280A6C398C2A7C399E280A1C398C2B1` would be "double encoding".

Anyway, the likely cause of question marks is

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.  -- Dump the Arabic text in HEX from Java.
- The column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this.  -- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for verification.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8. -- Theoretically, you dealt with this via `&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`.